# Atmosphere Framework Integration with spring MVC mapping not found in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, atmosphere

web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

     <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"

     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee

     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">


 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>chatbook</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.MeteorServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.servlet</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/chatbook-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>chatbook</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/chatbook/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

my chatbook-servlet.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">



<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.chatbook.web.controllers">
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven>

</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="jspResolveToViews"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jspfiles/">
</property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>


<mvc:resources location="/staticresources/" mapping="/static/**" ></mvc:resources>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename"
    value="com.chatbook.web.localizeMessages.messages">
</property>
</bean>
```

my controller:

```
@Controller

public class ChatController{

@RequestMapping("/")

public String showSignUp(){

return "signup";

}

}
```

I m trying to integrate Atmosphere with spring MVC but its not take me to right requestmapping and get this warning:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/chatbook/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'chatbook'
```

I am using tomcat 7 server and set connector tag in server.xml with

```
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
```

Please help me anyone tell me correct onfiguration of atmoshphere framework(runtime 2.4.7) with spring mvc..thanks